# Run a job, that was scheduled multiple times, only once per queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I am looking for a Laravel native way to permit a job, that was scheduled multiple times, to run only once, in the same queue list.

For example, a job named UpdateNumClients can be triggered multiple times, and pushed to the job queue ... that number of times. I am looking for a way to permit this job to only run once for the whole list.

Basically Laravel checks before running the job if there's another one queued, with the same arguments, then skips this one in hand, and delays execution to the last one scheduled of the same type and arguments.

Comment: It would be fun to implement this myself, but I am looking for something native to Laravel itself.

Comment: [unique job](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#unique-jobs)? though you will need drivers that supports atomic locking.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are looking for this.

https://divinglaravel.com/dispatching-unique-jobs-to-laravel-queues

I hope this help

Comment: Promising. But wont work in this scenario. The lock denies triggering the job until x seconds has passed. Thus, for example if you wish to monitor a client consumption/usage of something, you will be able to do that up to point before the lock is created, but after that, you wont be able to trigger the job and update your monitoring count.

Comment: This approach avoid duplication on queue as you stated in your question. If one job named UpdateNumClients is dispatched and locked in cache for 120 seg, what will happen is that this job will not be dispatched until lock being released by handle method or by expiration in cache.

Comment: If you, for example, will be counting something and storing that count, it wont be correct, because the count will be stopped during the lock period. Thus, any data added after the lock wont be counted. Until the job is dispateched again. And if you will be charging them based on that count for example, it wont be correct!